# Mono-Service2 - Init.d script not working

Tags: c#, linux, amazon-ec2, mono, windows-services

I have created the init.d script below for my C# windows service to be executed on an Amazon Linux EC2 Instance. I hope Amazon linux is based on fedora linux.

I have below init.d script and I googled and found the script.

but if I start the service using the following command:

```
sudo service amaziersysd start
```

I am getting below error message:

> cat: /tmp/amaziersysd.lock: No such file or directory

Pls note : I am newbie in setting up mono, and I am running mono 3.2.3 built from source.

```
#!/bin/sh

daemon_name=amaziersysd

if [ -f /etc/init.d/functions ]; then
  . /etc/init.d/functions
elif [ -f /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions ] ; then
  . /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions
else
  exit 0
fi

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mono/mono-service2
NAME=amaziersysd
DESC=amaziersysd

MONOSERVER=$(which mono-service2)
MONOSERVER_PID=$(cat /tmp/amaziersysd.lock)

case "$1" in
 start)
  stat_busy "Starting amaziersysd"
  if [ -z "${MONOSERVER_PID}" ]; then
   ${MONOSERVER} -l:/tmp/amaziersysd.lock /etc/amazierlb/sysdaemon/Amazier.CollectSysStat.exe
   stat_done
  else
   echo "amaziersysd is already running!"
   stat_fail
  fi
 ;;
 stop)
  stat_busy "Stopping amaziersysd"
  if [ -n "${MONOSERVER_PID}" ]; then
   kill ${MONOSERVER_PID}
   rm /tmp/amaziersysd.lock
   stat_done
  else
   echo "amaziersysd is not running"
   stat_fail
  fi
 ;;
 restart)
  $0 stop
  sleep 1
  $0 start
  stat_done
 ;;
 *)
  echo "usage: $0 {start|stop|restart}"
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: This is because in `MONOSERVER_PID=$(cat /tmp/amaziersysd.lock)` you do not have the `/tmp/amaziersysd.lock` file.

Comment: should i need to create that file ? what content i supposed to put in ?

Comment: It depends on the logic you want to apply. What looks normal to me is to create the file when you `start` the program and remove it when you `stop` it. This is the way to prevent the program not executing twice. But you can also check with `ps -ef` if the process is ON.

Comment: hi the process is not even starting . the script is stop executing at this line. at: /tmp/amaziersysd.lock: No such file or directory

Comment: i believe its pid lock file. how to create this file ?